# Segmented linear regression with fixed number of break points

Tags: segmented-regression

I would like to perform linear regression on a growth curve. Due to treatments I expect the growth to change not at all, once ore twice.
Therefore I want to test wether my growth curve is best fitted with a linear regression (on log-transform data) with 0,1 or two breakpoints. I also would like to get the timing of the breaks and do not define them, just the number of breaks. Afterwards I would like to asked which model fits the data best.

require(segmented)
out.lm<-lm(A1~Time,data=data)
o<-segmented(out.lm, seg.Z= ~Time, psi=NA,control=seg.control(display=TRUE,K=2,stop.if.error=FALSE))
slope(o)

plot(o,conf.levels=0.95,shade=TRUE)
points(o,link=FALSE,col=2)
points(data$Time,data$A1)

which gives me the following plot:

Comment: The plot image is missing. In addition, if you want help regarding R coding, try stackoverflow.com instead.